# DIV tag inside of P looking weird in the DOM tree

Tags: html, dom

Looking at any web inspector, the following markup is outputting unexpected (at least to me) results:

```
<p>
    <div>Here's a div!</div>
    And here's some text. 
    <div>Here's another div!</div>
</p>
```

Using Chrome's Dev Tools, I'm seeing the DOM tree look like this:

[image: screen shot of DOM Tree using Chrome's Dev Tools]

Maybe I'm having a brain fart, but shouldn't the DIV be inside of the P tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid html to put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.  The `<p>` element is only meant to include inline elements.  `<div>` is a block element.  See section [9.3.1 of the HTML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) for more info.

Chrome will sometimes rewrite bad HTML to be valid.

Here is a related/duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441639/how-can-i-put-div-in-p).

Comment: Awesome. I figured that was the case and that it was covered somewhere in the spec but I couldn't find it or a SO question related to it. Thanks!