# Why $('<p><div></div></p>') returns array of more than one node?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm confused with `$.parseHTML()` function. I thought that if the source html has a single root node this function should return an array with a single DOM node (the root node) with all the content attached as children.
It works that way most of the time, for example:

```
var nodes = $.parseHTML('<div><div>foo</div></div>');
console.debug(nodes.length); // prints 1
```

However if the root node is `<p>` then the structure of DOM nodes is lost and the HTML gets exploded to multiple disconnected nodes:

```
var nodes = $.parseHTML('<p><div>foo</div></p>');
console.debug(nodes.length); // prints 3
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahagukbd/1/) where you can try these cases.

It doesn't make any difference if I use `$(html)` or `$.parseHTML(html)`.

What is so special about `<p>` ? Why is it parsed in a different way? 
It this a bug or a feature?

Comment: `$.parseHTML('<p><div>foo</div></p>')` result in `<p></p><div>fooo</div><p></p>`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it) is about it, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441639/how-can-i-put-div-in-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it's because paragraph tags can't have divs inside of it. You can read more about it in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763952/1234502

Answer (score 5):

That's because when the HTML code is parsed, it doesn't end up with a single root node.

You can't have a block element inside a paragraph, so the paragraph ends where the `div` element starts. Then the ending tag for the paragraph becomes a second paragraph node.

The elements that you end up with are therefore:

```
<p></p>
<div>foo></div>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) clearly states:

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain [block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline) (including P itself).

And to see the effect try doing inspect element on `<p><div>foo</div></p>` 
you will see that the code fragment has been parsed to

```
<p></p>
<div>foo></div>
<p></p>
```

[image]