# Why are my paragraphs closing erratically?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on some markup for an internal site, and laying out a list of contacts in a series of rows. Right now, I'm laying this out with `<div>` tags:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <button type="button" id="createNewContact" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            Create
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I get the sort of markup you'd expect. You know, exactly what I typed in to Visual Studio. I'd like a bit more breathing room between rows, and I want to switch to `<p>` tags:

```
<p class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <button type="button" id="createNewContact" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            Create
        </button>
    </div>
</p>
```

Whenever I do that, my markup craps out in the browser:

```
<p class="row">
    </p><div class="col-md-5">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="createNewContact" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            Create
        </button>
    </div>
<p></p>
```

This happens no matter what browser I use. I've experimented with moving the `<p>` tags around, and putting them around `<div>` and `<fieldset>` tags (at least) produce this markup.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to switch to the paragraph tag? Also If you want to add some spacing you can always just add a break tag (</br>) it'll add a line break with some spacing.

Comment: I dislike `<br>` tags. I'd rather have the formatting baked into the structure of my markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `<p>` cannot contain a `<div>` or other block elements the browser will always take out the `<div>` out of the `<p>`

A `<p>` is created to contain text or other inline elements like `<span>`.

This has nothing to do with VS or Bootstrap, is it just html

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441639/how-can-i-put-div-in-p) answer

Comment: Sigh. You're right -- I misread the spec. I was looking at the tag omission section here (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) and interpreted the "element's end tag may be omitted" section as some kind of syntax error I was running into.

Comment: And, of course, as soon as I switch them to `<span>` tags, it works as expected. Goes to show that even an someone who's done this for a long time can have a major lapse. Thanks.