# not open second menu of accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using this accordion menu.

**JavaScript:**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion"), i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

**Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
    <p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div id="foo" class="panel">
        <p>
            <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
            <div id="foo" class="panel">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to use the second menu in section 3. I add in this accordion menu to another accordion menu but it does not open. Any ideas why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following HTML structure, I'm replacing `P` tag with `DIV` tag. The `P` element cannot contain block level elements like DIV.

Ref: [How can I put DIV in P?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441639/how-can-i-put-div-in-p) and [P tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P)

```
<body>
    <h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
    <p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>
    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div id="foo" class="panel">
        <div>
            <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
            <div id="foo" class="panel">
                <div>
                  test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The click event didn't work for your original HTML structure, as the browser altered the DOM elements and DIV element was removed from inside of P tag(explained the reason with the above reference links). This DOM change has resulted in an issue while we retrieve `nextElementSibling`.

Accept this answer if it solves your issue.