# laravel blade rendering for p tag

Tags: php, laravel

In the development of the use of Laravel to do, I have encountered a problem that I have not encountered before. I would like to cycle in a p tag inside some Div. Similar effects are as follows:

```
<p>
  @foreach($list as $val)
  <div>{{ $val }}</div>
  @endforeach
</p>
//it's supposed to be like this
<p>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
</p>
```

However, I can not achieve the desired effect, my code and results are as follows:

```
<p>
@foreach($val['userList'] as $v)
<div class="km-member clearfloat m_bottom" data-user_id="{{ $v->id }}">
  <div class="km-member-pic">
    <i class="km-member-bg"></i>
    <img src="{{ $v->avatar }}" alt="" class="km-member-img">
  </div>
  <span>{{ $v->realname }}</span>
  <i class="km-icon-delete"></i>
</div>
@endforeach
</p>
```

In the browser has become this way:

[image]

Comment: take div instead of p tag and check the output, I am 80% sure it will work, and I can say, p tag is not that neccessary to only take

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441639/how-can-i-put-div-in-p#answer-5441670

Comment: @rahul_m it's success, I know how to solve, thank you. Is the html element of the problem, I thought it was laravel rendering problem